# Measuring the rotation angle of stepper motor

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I have a [hc-sr04](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf) ultrasonic sensor. I am considering to put this sensor on a board which rotates by stepper motor. Sensor starts to rotate and detect an object during this rotation. Is there a way that I can measure the rotation angle of the stepper motor? Or can I get the number of steps that stepper turns after detection? Microcontroller is ARDUINO UNO. I read some answers about this topic but it is not clear yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by the asker for years with no indication if the suggested and standard method of counting the steps issued has solved the problem or not.  If it has not, the question would be unanswerable without further input from the asker.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just keep track of the number of steps you have given the stepper driver. Usually a counter is used in the program. On power-up you would rotate the arm until a 'home' switch is made, zero your counter and then keep track from then on. It's a very simple and economical method and is used in thousands of applications including, for example, dot-matrix and inkjet printers.

Stepper control is generally 'open loop'. This means that if the arm in your application gets blocked or stalled the program position counter will not know and will be out of sync with the real position.

Step angle will be determined by your motor and whether you're using full-step, half-step or some micro-step mode.